# Git Push from release branch on the main and develop branch on Github

Tags: git, github, version-control, push

I'm trying to get into versioning with Git but I'm struggling a bit.
If I follow good practices, I have to create several branches (`main`, `develop`, `hotfix`, `feature` and `release`).

When I'm on my `release` branch, I want to update my `main` branch, and the `develop` branch.

```
$ git checkout main
// Switched to branch 'main'
$ git merge --no-ff release-1.2
$ git tag -a 1.2
$ git checkout develop
// Switched to branch 'develop'
$ git merge --no-ff release-1.2
$ git branch -d release-1.2
// Deleted branch release-1.2
```

I don't understand how to then push the code to my remote repository and update the code on the `develop` and `main` branch.

Here the `main` branch is updated.

```
$ git push origin main
```

I tried this to do it on both branches but it only updated the `develop` branch

```
git push -f -u origin develop main
```

**Is my git usage wrong and should I only update the main on the remote repository on github?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do a lot with few, when you just start using git.

But first, somenthing I think you do in the wrong order. You should start with develop, create a branch, make changes, merge into develop. It works?, ok, merge into release (pre-production), It works?, yes, ok, merge it into master, It works?, yes, delete the brach you create.

Anyway, there are different flows to work with git.

Answer your questions - Do all the steps:

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git merge --no-ff release-1.2
$ git push -u origin develop
```

Now you have release-1.2 changes into develop, in your local, and the remote repository.

```
$ git checkout main
$ git merge --no-ff release-1.2
$ git tag -a 1.2
$ git push -u origin main
```

Now you have the changes from release-1.2 in main local, and in the remote.

```
$ git branch -d release-1.2
```

And finally you delete the branch.

Starts with the basics, search a flow that fit your work, with the easy commands, and don't use what you don't understand. Try to do not use a cool command that can do a lot of things in one step.